Resource usage summary by user
Backstory:
I have VPS server running Ubuntu 20.04. For each different "service" I'm running, there is a user which has all necessary processes running in screens. To occasionally monitor resource usage I'm using top.
Problem:
I want "top-like" command which lists users instead of processes and shows summary of resources usage by user. I wonder if there is some package already implementing such feature? Or would I have to make some script to do that for me?

If you enable "process accounting", and don't let /var/log/account/pacct fill uour disk. It gets a binary log entry every time a process (any process) terminates. To test for a day: sudo touch /var/log/account/pacc;sudo acct on;sudo at "now + 1 day"  acct off. Then us psacct and acct to look at the log.
